# Is it possible to Discretize a Continuous Time Markov Chain?

Tags: probability, markov-process

In a Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC), the following properties are said to hold:

- Discrete (Embedded Jump Process):

$$P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{i} q_{ij}}$$
$$q_{ij} = \lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{P_{ij}(h)}{h}$$

- Continuous Part (Kolmogorov):

$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = P(t)Q$$
$$P(t) = e^{tQ}$$
$$\exp(Qt) = I + Qt + \frac{1}{2!} Q^2t^2 + \frac{1}{3!} Q^3t^3 + \ldots$$

I always wondered if in a CTMC, you can skip the Kolmogorov Equation and analyze the continuous part using the discrete approximation.

For some very small $h$, remove the limit and write:

$$ h \cdot q_{ij} =  P_{ij} (h)$$

Rearranging the first equation:

$$q_{ij} = P_{ij} \cdot \sum_{i} q_{ij}$$

Thus:

$$ P_{ij} (h) =  P_{ij} \cdot h \cdot {\sum_{i} q_{ij}}   $$

Now, I could ask the question: Given that I am currently in state $i$, what is the probability that after 10 seconds I will be in state $j$ ? In a CTMC, this kind of question is traditionally answered using the relationships derived from the Kolmogorov Equations.

However in my case, I could break 10 seconds into 1000 small intervals of 0.001:

$$10 = 0.001 + 0.001 + .... + 0.001$$

So very crudely, I could take the embedded discrete chain and say:

$$ P_{ij} (10) = P ^ {1000} $$

That is, identify the  $p_{ij}$ element in the discrete chain raised to the power of 1000.

I understand that is a very inefficient and computationally expensive way to deal with a CTMC, but I was just wondering is this approach statistically logical?